# CSS: How to fine tune breakpoints for col-sm-X classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have some HTMl that looks like this:

```
<Row>
<Col class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4"> //Content here <Col>
<Col class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4"> //Content here  <Col>
<Col class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4"> //Content here  <Col>
</Row>
```

Genrally this works well, but for some devices the breakpoints are not like I want them to be how can I use media querys to specify what class I should apply for what screen size.. or override the defualt behaviour of bootstrap but NOT globally, I just want to target this bit of the HTML.

Comment: You could just add a class to the column and then specify your own breakpoints? Probably the easiest way, if you don't want the changes to be global...

Comment: @JoeCzucha I was thinking about doing that... is there a list of what col-md-x actually do... so I can do it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a class to the column and then specify your own breakpoints? Probably the easiest way, if you don't want the changes to be global...

You can find the list of Bootstrap breakpoints in the [compiled source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css); and that should be enough to tweak the functionality that you need.